# Will $.getJSON work with PhoneGap build?

Tags: javascript, cordova, xmlhttprequest, getjson, content-security-policy

Is anyone able to get this to work in their PhoneGap build? :

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://reddit.com/.json", function(data){
        alert("Success!");
    })
})
```

It works fine in browsers but when I build the app it doesn't run.

I've added these to my config.xml already to whitelist all domains

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Also tried building it with this CSP and without

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

which I got from here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Your CSP isn't going to allow Ajax requests outside your app.  What actual error message do you see in the JS console or other logging?

Comment: When its opened in the browser it works fine, but when built with PhoneGap I can't see what happens in the app. Is there any way to check for error messages after its built?

Comment: You could use http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/debugging_remote_debugging_tools.md.html to be honest I'd just build it locally which gives you better options with Chrome remote debugging for Android and Safari for iOS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, to be honest if I knew how I would but this is all still new to me I just came into this with HTML CSS and some basic skills in javascript :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at this and replicated your Ajax request in my own PhoneGap Build project.

What I noticed was that the URL you are using http://reddit.com/.json seems to get redirected on Android devices at least to https://www.reddit.com/.json

I discovered this by doing a PhoneGap Build build with debug turned on, running the .apk on a Nexus 7 with Chrome remote debugger tools attached, and seeing this in the JS Console:

"Refused to connect to 'https://www.reddit.com/.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy..."

I fixed this by amending the Content Security Policy meta tag in index.html to include both https://www.reddit.com and http://reddit.com in the connect-src clause.  Rebuilt on PhoneGap Build using this CSP and it works fine on the Nexus 7 now:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://reddit.com https://www.reddit.com">
```

So my PhoneGap application now looks like this and works:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        $.getJSON('http://reddit.com/.json', function(data){
            alert('Success - got ' + data.data.children.length + ' children in JSON');
        });
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

For your convenience I put the complete app ready for PhoneGap Build in a Github repo [here](https://github.com/simonprickett/pgbuilddemo).  Feel free to use this as you need.

Comment: You don't even know how excited I am to see this solution work. Thank you so much @Simon. I figured it was a problem with the config.xml file or Javascript